# how to create a single-direction IK leg with a direction controller?

Tags: rigging

One of the things i'd like to do is create an IK that only bends forward and backward on a single local axis. At the top, I want a control to change the direction of that axis.

so the ik goes only forward and back, no sideways movement. And I control which direction forward is.

I can't get this to work with Limit Location or constraint combination I've tried so far. It messes with the overall direction control or the placement of the foot after the chain :(

I'm rigging a robot, and due to the (very specific) placement of his parts, his legs only bend one way, with a rotater cup as a hip socket. I can't quite figure out how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Thank you in advance,

Allen

Comment: I figured it out!!! Omg. Simple yet complex. Rigging is so much fun lol. :P

Answer (score 1):

In order to get it to work, the leg IK target bone  has a child of constraint to the rotater. The foot has an IK as well with a length of 1, and its target is parented to the leg IK.

Pretty tricky.